# Equivalence despite non-bijective function

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, logic

a friend of mine and me have an argument about the usage of equivalence. I think it is fine to write the following:

$x^2 = a \iff \left(x = \sqrt{a} \lor x = - \sqrt{a} \right)$

He thinks this is no logical equivalence (but an implication) because of the non-bijectivity of the functions involved (squaring and thaking the root). I think algebraically this doesn't matter, for real numbers there can only be two options for the solution (while the other implication is trivial). Could somebody provide maybe a short proof or tell me that I am wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are assuming the ["principal value" od SQRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root). If not, we cannot write $\sqrt a$ because the notation $f(x)$ is well defined only when $f$ is a function.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. If it weren't possible to use an equivalence to define a non-injective function, how would you define a non-injective function?